# IF pulling through the 'wrong' cell value

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

The goal of my script is to email me a cell value, if the cell does not contain the text "Not Ready".

In the cell range I2:I8, every cell except I2 contains the text "Not Ready". Therefore the information in I2 should be emailed to me.

When I run the script, I'm unexpectedly emailed contents of a different cell in the range. This cell is the same as the others in the range.

My hunch is the cell range contains an IF formula rather than a text string which may be the cause.

```
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
 options = [
  {name:"Scan and Email", functionName:"readSheet"},
 ];
  ss.addMenu("Email", options);

 function readSheet() {

 var ss = 
 SpreadsheetApp.openById("GOOGLE SHEET");
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("formResponses")
   var range = sheet.getRange("I2:I8")
 var data = range.getValue();

 if (data != "Not Ready") 

  MailApp.sendEmail("MY EMAIL ADDRESS", "Test Update", "Action:" 
+data+ ".");

 }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range contains more than one cell, so `range.getValues()`. Retuned data is an array. Array will never equal to a string. Replace -

```
var data = range.getValue();
if (data != "Not Ready") 
  MailApp.sendEmail("MY EMAIL ADDRESS", "Test Update", "Action:" +data+ ".");
}
```

with -

```
var data = range.getValues();
var ready = data.filter(function(el) {
  return el[0] != 'Not Ready';
});
if (!ready.length) return;
MailApp.sendEmail('MY EMAIL ADDRESS', 'Test Update', 'Action:' + ready[0][0] + '.');
```

Comment: Technically, it's a two dimentional array. So, `el[0] !== 'Not Ready';` is more accurate.

Comment: above works only if 0th el is the only one to meet condition. i thought any cell in range could meet it.

Comment: It'll always be the 0th element if it's a column. `I2:I4`  will look like `[[I2],[I3],[I4]]`. `el` will be `[I2]` and `el[0]` will be value `I2` in the first iteration. `el` will be `[I3]` and `el[0]` will be value `I3` in the second iteration and so on.

Comment: ah, I missed the range is actually a column. thanks! edited code to reflect that.

Comment: Big thanks for this! I'm running into a new problem, I now get the error ."Script function not found: readSheet", and can't get to the bottom of it. Do you have any ideas at all?

Comment: `readSheet()` function is inside `onOpen()` function. try taking it outside of all function